# Substitute the values ​of the array starting from the 3 element

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have an array that returns the values ​​of my RangeList (Calendar Sheet) with the  `var val`.

Inside this main array, I have another array that extracts the tasks matching the day of the month from the calendar sheet (the day of the month from the calendar sheet is the first element of each array in the main array).

As I said, this secondary array returns the matching results for each calendar day in the `var resultados`.

After that, I create another for loop so that it generates the results one by one so that I can paste these results into the rows of each range within the RangeList. But I want to paste the results from element 2 of the array, because element 0 is the day of the month, and element 1 is busy. After that, 13 empty elements are available within the array into which to paste the results of the matching tasks.
I do this with `val.splice(2, 0, results[i]);`

**However, I am having two problems.**

1. I want to paste the results from element 2. I was guided by the documentation that splice could splice values, and according to the console log, it actually inserts the values, however, instead of replacing the element in question, it is adding elements extras in the indicated position. This means that each array instead of having 15 elements in total (whether with values ​​or empty), each array ends up having the 15 initial elements + extra elements that have been incorporated when pasting the results of the matching tasks. (EDIT: THIS PROBLEM IS RESOLVED)
2. The second problem I have is that in the console log I can see that the matching tasks have been inserted in each range of the RangeList. However, my worksheet does not display any results. I do not understand why. I've even tried .push and no actual results are displayed in my spreadsheet either. Only in the apps script console log with `Logger.log(valValues);`

**These are my doubts:**

1. How can I replace the current elements from position 2 to position 14 the array with the result of each matching task of the for loop `resultados` (EDIT: THIS PROBLEM IS RESOLVED)
2. How can I get this to be displayed in the worksheet, and not just in the google apps script log console.

[Here is a sample sheet to reproduce the error and with the complete code.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1S1daQLMzrTi7eWxHgcsDhzhXOE8oZYKYOntO2Q0alvU/copy)

Here I leave a part of the code. The complete part is inside the attached sample sheet.

```
function importarTareasGlobal(){

  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheetTareas = ss.getSheetByName(' Tareas/Eventos');  // Hoja Origen
  const sheetCalendario = ss.getSheetByName(' Calendario (pruebas)');  // Hoja Destino
  var lastRowTareas = sheetTareas.getLastRow();  // Obtenemos la ultima fila de la hoja "Tareas/Eventos"

  // We get the month and year from the "Calendar" sheet.

    var calendarioMes = sheetCalendario.getRange("A6").getValue();
    var calendarioAño = sheetCalendario.getRange("A10").getValue();
    var mesYaño = new Date('3' + calendarioMes + calendarioAño);
    var mesCalendario = mesYaño.getMonth();
    var añoCalendario = mesYaño.getFullYear();

  // Target range.

    var filasDestino = sheetCalendario.getRangeList(['E4:E18', 'H4:H18', 'K4:K18', 'N4:N18', 'Q4:Q18', 'T4:T18', 'W4:W18', 'E20:E34', 'H20:H34', 'K20:K34', 'N20:N34', 'Q20:Q34', 'T20:T34', 'W20:W34', 'E36:E50', 'H36:H50', 'K36:K50', 'N36:N50', 'Q36:Q50', 'T36:T50', 'W36:W50', 'E52:E66', 'H52:H66', 'K52:K66', 'N52:N66', 'Q52:Q66', 'T52:T66', 'W52:W66', 'E68:E82', 'H68:H82', 'K68:K82', 'N68:N82', 'Q68:Q82', 'T68:T82', 'W68:W82', 'E84:E98', 'H84:H98', 'K84:K98', 'N84:N98', 'Q84:Q98', 'T84:T98', 'W84:W98']);

    var filasDestinoVal = filasDestino.getRanges();

  // Search range (tasks/events sheet)

    var tabladebusqueda = sheetTareas.getRange("B5:H" + lastRowTareas);  // Range of the tasks/events sheet where the search will be made
    var tabladebusquedaVal = tabladebusqueda.getValues();
    Logger.log(tabladebusquedaVal);

  // Create a 2D array with a cell address and date value for each cell

  var valValues = [];

  filasDestinoVal.forEach(row => {
    var val = row.getValues();  // Get the values ​​of the rows of each target range of the calendar
    Logger.log(val);  // Value of each range in 2D array
    valValues.push(val);
    
    var diaMes = val[0]; // Get the value of the first cell of each destination range, that is, the day of the month.
    //Logger.log(diaMes);
    
    // Compare the dates of the tasks with the calendar day and get the matching tasks

    var resultados = [];  // Here we get the icon + task of the matching tasks

    tabladebusquedaVal.forEach(r => {
      var fechaTarea = new Date(r[5]);
      var icono = r[1];
      var tarea = r[2];
      var icoTarea = icono + ' ' + tarea;
      var checkbox = r[0];      
      
      if ( fechaTarea.getDate() == diaMes && fechaTarea.getMonth() == mesCalendario && fechaTarea.getFullYear() == añoCalendario ) {
        resultados.push([icoTarea]);
      }

    });

    Logger.log(resultados);

    // Cconvert the results from 2D to 1D

    for (var i = 0; i<resultados.length; i++){
      val.splice(2+i, 1, resultados[i])  // Paste the results into the arrays of the first loop filasdestino.forEach
    }

  });

  Logger.log(valValues);
  
}
```

Comment: Your example is incomplete and thus not reproducible and investigate the possibility of  using a batch method of an api

Comment: @Cooper I don't understand why you say that my sample sheet is incomplete and the error cannot be reproduced. I just logged in and I was able to reproduce the error without any problems. When accessing the link, you have to make a copy and then you can access the work. The complete code needed is there and works fine. Anyway I am going to modify my code in this post and I am going to put the complete code to see if this helps.

Comment: @Cooper I also tried to incorporate all the tasks at once, but the `var valValues` ​​returned an array in one way and the `var valores` ​​(`valores.push(resultados);`) returned the array in another way and I didn't know how to proceed. That's why I opted for this individualized form. I'm new to code and I have my limitations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of the 0 you're not actually replacing values. Try changing this line:

```
val.splice(2, 0, resultados[i])
```

With

```
val.splice(2+i, 1, resultados[i])
```

And see if it generates your expected output. `2+i` allows you to navigate through the different indexes and `1` deletes that single element

Comment: Thank you so much! Effectively, this solved the problem with the array. However I still can't see the results in the worksheet. The results are only displayed in the google apps script console.

Comment: I can't access your sheet's code with my phone, but use: `range.setValues(results)` change `range` if needed with the variable you actually use for the desired range

Comment: This doesn't work for me. Edit the code of my post and put the complete code. Maybe this can help you figure out the problem?